# Generators in arithmetic progression.

Tags: primitive-roots, arithmetic-progressions

Suppose $p+1$ is a prime fix $a,b\in\Bbb Z_p^\times$ how many generators of $\Bbb Z_p^\times$ lie on the line $ax+b$ considered over $\Bbb Z$ and what is the size of a typical minimal generator with respect to $a,b$ in average case whenever a generator exists?

Comment: Maybe I'm unclear about the question, but shouldn't one be able to solve for any generator on the line $ax+b$?  Since $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ is cyclic (for odd primes), it should have $\phi(p-1)$ generators, which I believe has a maximum value of $\frac{p-1}{2}-1$ and a minimum value when $p$ is $1$ more than a primorial.

Comment: $ax+b$ is considered over $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Apologies, I don't quite understand the significance of that.  Wouldn't that just mean it solves $ax+b=g$ over and over again for each generator g?

Comment: I dont understand your comment. we can have many generators and $x\in\Bbb Z$ has to hold and $0<ax+b<p-1$ has to hold.

Comment: Ok sorry, I hope someone can answer